# Php Session username Presatashop

Tags: php, session, cookies, prestashop

After logging in to my website , logging page shows users name, but going back to home page it shows again to sign it..Only the label is problem and all other features like shopping, searching everything else works fine. ie. same as user has logged in.'sign in' label appears instead of 'sign out'

Similarly when user has logged out it shows the username but user cant do any thing like shopping, view account details, etc.ie.same as user has logged out. but the 'username' appears instead of 'sign in' label.
i'm using prestashop. and this happens only in sign in page and home page

```
<!-- Block user information module NAV  -->
{if $logged}
<div class="header_user_info">
    <a href="{$link->getPageLink('my-account', true)|escape:'html'}" title="{l s='View my customer account' mod='blockuserinfo'}" class="account" rel="nofollow"><span>{$cookie->customer_firstname} {$cookie->customer_lastname}</span></a>
</div>
{/if}
<div class="header_user_info">
    {if $logged}
        <a class="logout" href="{$link->getPageLink('index', true, NULL, "mylogout")|escape:'html'}" rel="nofollow" title="{l s='Log me out' mod='blockuserinfo'}">{l s='Sign out' mod='blockuserinfo'}</a>
    {else}
        <a class="login" href="{$link->getPageLink('my-account', true)|escape:'html'}" rel="nofollow" title="{l s='Log in to your customer account' mod='blockuserinfo'}">{l s='Sign in' mod='blockuserinfo'}</a>
    {/if}
</div>
<!-- /Block user information module NAV -->
```

Comment: yes,, sometimes  it shows to 'sign in' when already signed in& it shows 'sign out'  and 'username' even after signed out. On refreshing it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this in .htacces solved my problem

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset Etag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 {if $logged}
    <div class="header_user_info">
        <a href="{$link->getPageLink('my-account', true)|escape:'html'}" title="{l s='View my customer account' mod='blockuserinfo'}" class="account" rel="nofollow"><span>{$cookie->customer_firstname} {$cookie->customer_lastname}</span></a>
    </div>
    {/if}
    <div class="header_user_info">
        {if !$logged}
            <a class="logout" href="{$link->getPageLink('index', true, NULL, "mylogout")|escape:'html'}" rel="nofollow" title="{l s='Log me out' mod='blockuserinfo'}">{l s='Sign out' mod='blockuserinfo'}</a>
        {else}
            <a class="login" href="{$link->getPageLink('my-account', true)|escape:'html'}" rel="nofollow" title="{l s='Log in to your customer account' mod='blockuserinfo'}">{l s='Sign in' mod='blockuserinfo'}</a>
        {/if}
    </div>
```